# regex fail on razor

Tags: regex

I have a simple regex - `[a-zA-Z0-9][^\s]` - that checks that there are at least two characters and the second one is not white space. This works fine in C# but not in an `<input>` field in Razor.

Here is the field in Razor:

```
<input type="search" name="search" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9][^\s]">
```

Here is a test in C#:

```
Console.WriteLine("string 'c-III' is valid = {0}", rgx.IsMatch("c-III"));
Console.WriteLine("string 'c ' is valid = {0}", rgx.IsMatch("c "));
```

Here is the result:

```
string 'c-III' is valid = True
string 'c ' is valid = False
```

This works as expected as well in regex101.com

When I type c-III I get the error message: Please match the requested format.

The expression needs to validate the following:

- minimum of 2 characters
- second character cannot be white space

I am not sure if the expression need to be adjusted or if the problem is somewhere else. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you show the relevant Razor?

Comment: sorry it was on the question but it got removed when I posted it... <input type="search" class="top-label" name="search" placeholder="search by name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9][^\s]">

Comment: That's not a Razor feature, but [an HTML5 feature](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp). So, are you using a compatible browser?

Comment: @Kenneth K. I am using using Chrome